# "How to find correct tags in nested HTML using Beautiful Soup, receiving list index out of range error or empty list"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Printing out the tags under ('a') works perfectly to bring out the description for each of the houses on the website. Trying to replicate this for the price using any tag('price' for example) doesn't work. Printing out everything under 'master-content' reveals all details including the price.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



convert_page = 'https://www.property24.co.mu/property-for-sale'


page = urlopen(convert_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')


name_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'master-content'})

textContent = []


try_again = name_box.find_all("price")

print (try_again)


house_name_list = soup.find(class_="resultsControl")



house_descriptions = house_name_list.find_all('a')
house_prices = house_name_list.find_all('price');
```

Output expected:

```
Rs 10 023 304

Rs 46 697 000

Rs 5 323 977
```

Output received:

```
[]
```

When trying to iterate over list:

List out of index(due to list being empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that function `house_name_list.find_all('price')` will try to find all tags `<price>`, not tags with `class=price`. You can change it to `house_name_list.find_all(class_="price")` to get all tags with prices.

To tie descriptions, prices and titles together, you can use `zip()` method:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

convert_page = 'https://www.property24.co.mu/property-for-sale'

page = urlopen(convert_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

for a, desc, price in zip(soup.select('.propertyTileWrapper > a:nth-of-type(1)'),
                          soup.select('.description'),
                          soup.select('.price')):
    print(a['title'])
    print(price.get_text(strip=True))
    print(desc.get_text(strip=True))
    print('-' * 160)
```

Prints:

```
3 Bedroom Apartment / Flat for sale in Roches Noires
Rs 10 023 304
Nice apartment located on the second floor within a secured residence in Azuri. The apartment offers three bedrooms, 2 bathrooms and a...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3 Bedroom Apartment / Flat for sale in Mon Choisy
Rs 46 697 000
This apartment with island decor exudes elegance and refinement. With 3 beautiful bedrooms in suite, the apartment offers a stunning view of...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3 Bedroom Apartment / Flat for sale in Flic En Flac
Rs 5 323 977
Project of 5 Duplex 120 m2 which comprises of: - Ground floor: 1 bedroom and 1 bathroom , kitchen, lounge /dining -...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4 Bedroom House for sale in Grande Rivière Noire
Rs 32 339 553
This splendid furnished house situated in Black River, its really spacious. It comprises of entrance hall, lounge (separate), dining (separate), guest cloakroom,...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4 Bedroom House for sale in Belle Vue Harel
Rs 40 343 794
This Luxury villa located right at the top of the Hillside Estate. It consists of 4 Bedrooms (3 en-suite), Lounge /Dining, TV...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```